# Python Syntax / List Slicing Question: What does this syntax mean?

Tags: python, list, delimiter, slice

```
lines = file('info.csv','r').readlines()

counts = []
for i in xrange(4):
    counts.append(fromstring(lines[i][:-2],sep=',')[0:-1])
```

If anyone can explain this code to me, it would be greatly appreciated. I can't seem to find more advanced examples on slicing--only very simple ones that don't explain this situation.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

A slice takes the form `o[start:stop:step]`, all of which are optional. `start` defaults to `0`, the first index. `stop` defaults to `len(o)`, the closed upper bound on the indicies of the list. `step` defaults to `1`, including every value of the list.

If you specify a negative value, it represents an offset from the end of the list. For example, `[-1]` access the last element in a list, and `-2` the second last.

If you enter a non-`1` value for step, you will include different elements or include them in a different order. `2` would skip every other element. `3` would skip two out of every three. `-1` would go backwards through the list.

#### `[:-2]`

Since `start` is omitted, it defaults to the beginning of the list. A `stop` of `-2` indicates to exclude the last two elements. So `o[:-2]` slices the list to exclude the last two elements.

#### `[0:-1]`

The `0` here is redundant, because it's what start would have defaulted to anyway. This is the same as the other slice, except that it only excludes the last element.

[From the Data model page of the Python 2.7 docs](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#index-841):

> Sequences also support slicing: `a[i:j]` selects all items with index `k` such that `i <= k < j`. When used as an expression, a slice is a sequence of the same type. This implies that the index set is renumbered so that it starts at 0.
>
> Some sequences also support “extended slicing” with a third “step” parameter: `a[i:j:k]` selects all items of a with index `x` where `x = i + n*k, n >= 0` and `i <= x < j`.

[The "what's new" section of the Python 2.3 documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/whatsnew/section-slices.html) discusses them as well, when they were added to the language.

Answer (score 5):

A good way to understand the slice syntax is to think of it as syntactic sugar for the equivalent `for` loop. For example:

```
L[a:b:c]
```

Is equivalent to (e.g., in C):

```
for(int i = a; i < b; i += c) {
    // slice contains L[i]
}
```

Where `a` defaults to `0`, `b` defaults to `len(L)`, and `c` defaults to `1`.

(And if `c`, the step, is a negative number, then the default values of `a` and `b` are reversed. This gives a sensible result for `L[::-1]`).

Then the only other thing you need to know is that, in Python, indexes "wrap around", so that `L[-1]` signifies the *last* item in the list, `L[-2]` is the second to last, and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

If `list` is a list then `list[-1]` is the last element of the list, `list[-2]` is the element before it and so on.

Also, `list[a:b]` means the list with all elements in `list` at positions between `a` and `b`. If one of them is missing, it is assumed to mean the end of the list. Thus, `list[2:]` is the list of all elements starting from `list[2]`. And `list[:-2]` is the list of all elements from `list[0]` to `list[-2]`.

In your code, the `[0:-1]` part it the same as `[:-1]`.